# Cannot access Reddit from my work or home computers

Tags: mac, browser

I work on a 27 inch iMac (2011) at home, and have a 27 inch iMac (2009) at work. For the last several days, I have not been able to access Reddit from these computers. This may occur on other domains, but so far it is the only one out of perhaps 100 domains that I have experienced this on.

Visiting the site in Chrome, Safari, or Firefox results in the following text:

> Invalid URL
>
> The requested URL "/", is invalid. Reference
>   #9.1f5c434d.1406941103.72cd1f5

Even incognito windows will provide the same result. What makes this weird is that I do not share configurations between my work and home computers. They are completely separate setups, and the most I ever do is copy some files between them via flash drive.

Additional Details:

- Turning on my mobile hotspot on my phone and using that internet
  connection allows me to reach Reddit.com
- About half of the time, all of reddit is accessible, except for [reddit.com/r/drupal](http://reddit.com/r/drupal). When this occurs, having someone at my work office visit reddit.com/r/drupal and then refreshing my browser will let me access the site....for about 20 minutes.
- Yet other times, I can access the site without fail. It almost seems random.
- All most recent versions of browsers, and OS X v10.9.2 on both machines

What could be happening here? My first thought was browser issue, which is obviously not the case as it is happening on 6 different browsers across 2 computers. Then, I thought perhaps my hosts file. Here are the contents of that file.

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
127.0.0.1        schematest.localhost
127.0.0.1        jstest
127.0.0.1        features
127.0.0.1        ksajdfoiuawef
```

I don't know how to really interpret this, but I don't really see anything that could be causing an issue, and I certainly have not modified anything on my computer like this in the last 6 months. Could this be a blockage on Reddit's end? I have been more active on [reddit.com/r/drupal](http://reddit.com/r/drupal) recently, asking for advice and feedback on some recent work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the same thing still happen when you try through a virtual machine eg. virtualbox or vmware?

Comment: Just try to clear your local dns once and try and see if that helps.

Comment: I get the same error when I go to http://reddit.com but it works if I use http://www.reddit.com . This just started a few days ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have reddit blocked on a router that you use... That, or Reddit is changing things on it's servers and it's not only down for you, but everyone else too.

I've had trouble with reddit before, and it was entirely on their end. If it hasn't been like this for too long, it may resolve itself.

Comment: It was on there end. Another comment on my question pointed out that the url without "www" no longer works, and that started a few days ago. No idea why they would disable that.

Comment: Yeah, for such a big site, reddit does some wierd things sometimes :) Glad it works for you now!